# How to automatically get IP address for running jupyter notebook in local network

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-20.04

I have two computers connected to same router using Lan cable. One computer is running jupyter notebook, and I want to access it from another computer.

So i use this command

> jupyter notebook --port 8888 --ip=192.168.1.12

How did I find this IP address? I typed this command

> nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24

And it printed a bunch of IP addresses. I tried them one by one, and If it is not free, i got this error

> OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Is there any way to automate this process? Finding correct IP Address?

If I restart PC or router, i need to find the new IP again. Is theree any way to keep a fixed IP?

Comment: What version of Jupyter are you discussing?

Comment: You need to specify a static IP address

Comment: How to find static IP @TinoD